# How do you create two (linked) sub-sites?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I've installed the Apostrophe 'blog' bundle, following the official instructions [here](https://github.com/punkave/apostrophe-blog). I'm now trying to create 2 separate 'sub-sites' where:

1) Blog pages:

- Site 1's blog page only displays blog posts about site 1
- Site 2's blog page only displays blog posts about site 2

2) General pages:

- Site 1's general pages only display content about site 1
- Site 2's general pages only display content about site 2

So to solve the BLOG question (1) I'd like to do the following, which is in the above instructions:

> Another approach is to extend the modules, creating new modules and a
>   completely separate admin bar item for managing the content. If you
>   take this approach, you must set a distinct name property when
>   configuring your subclass of apostrophe-blog, such as article. This
>   will be value of type in the database for each blog post of this
>   subclass.

Unfortunately I can't work out exactly how to do that - I've tried various things in app.js to extend the blog module, but I keep getting:

> Error while constructing the XXX module Error: The module XXX has an
>   alias, blog, that conflicts with a module registered earlier or a core
>   Apostrophe feature.

Comment: It would be helpful to post the original and extension's configuration. Have you tried setting an `alias` to a different name in the complaining module?

Answer (score 0):

You can just make two "apostrophe-blog" pages (Blog1 & Blog2) linked to different tags (blog1 & blog2 defined on page properties).

Now, when you create a blog post, you choose the correct tag to make appear the post in the right page.